# 32-bit pointer overflow in 64-bit gcc code - fails in compile

Tags: pointers, gcc, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a very large legacy Fortran 90 code (screamer) with gFortran on a Mac (2.2 GHz Intel Core i7) running Yosemite. (gFortran V5.1.0) I have 16 GB of RAM. The code is memory intensive and I am trying to increase array sizes to solve larger problems. I have maintained the code for >10 years and rewriting 200,000 lines of code right now is not an option. As I carefully increase the size of the 2-D matrix (am(max_nodes, max_nodes)) and several 1-D vectors (RHS(max_nodes) and a(max_nodes*2)) by varying the integer "max_nodes" I eventually get to a 32-bit pointer limit (4 byte unsigned integer limit) during compilation. See below.

final section layout:

```
__TEXT/__text addr=0x100001390, size=0x0006B9CB, fileOffset=0x00001390, type=1
__TEXT/__text_startup addr=0x10006CD60, size=0x00000041,    fileOffset=0x0006CD60, type=1
__TEXT/__text_exit addr=0x10006CDB0, size=0x00000031, fileOffset=0x0006CDB0, type=1
__TEXT/__stubs addr=0x10006CDE2, size=0x00000252, fileOffset=0x0006CDE2, type=28
__TEXT/__stub_helper addr=0x10006D034, size=0x000003EE, fileOffset=0x0006D034, type=32
__TEXT/__cstring addr=0x10006D428, size=0x0000CFCB, fileOffset=0x0006D428, type=13
__TEXT/__const addr=0x10007A400, size=0x00008F00, fileOffset=0x0007A400, type=0
__TEXT/__eh_frame addr=0x100083300, size=0x0000DCF8, fileOffset=0x00083300, type=19
__DATA/__got addr=0x100091000, size=0x00000060, fileOffset=0x00091000, type=29
__DATA/__nl_symbol_ptr addr=0x100091060, size=0x00000010, fileOffset=0x00091060, type=29
__DATA/__la_symbol_ptr addr=0x100091070, size=0x00000318, fileOffset=0x00091070, type=27
__DATA/__mod_init_func addr=0x100091388, size=0x00000010,  fileOffset=0x00091388, type=33
__DATA/__mod_term_func addr=0x100091398, size=0x00000008, fileOffset=0x00091398, type=34

__DATA/__const addr=0x1000913A0, size=0x000007C8, fileOffset=0x000913A0, type=0
__DATA/__static_data addr=0x100091B68, size=0x00000003, fileOffset=0x00091B68, type=0
__DATA/__data addr=0x100091B80, size=0x000003E0, fileOffset=0x00091B80, type=0
__DATA/__bss4 addr=0x100091F60, size=0x00000018, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__bss5 addr=0x100091F80, size=0x00020000, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__bss3 addr=0x1000B1F80, size=0x00000028, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__pu_bss2 addr=0x1000B1FA8, size=0x00000008, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__bss2 addr=0x1000B1FB0, size=0x00000024, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__pu_bss5 addr=0x1000B1FE0, size=0x0000024C, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__pu_bss4 addr=0x1000B2230, size=0x00000018, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__common addr=0x1000B2260, size=0x000020D8, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__zo_bss3 addr=0x1000B4338, size=0x00000021, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
__DATA/__huge addr=0x1000B4360, size=0x984EB80C, fileOffset=0x00000000, type=25
```

ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (2147639505 max is +/-4GB): from _main_loop_ (0x10000E120) to _a.4206 (0x180034380) in '_main_loop_' from screamer64.a(main_loop.o) for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

In this error message main_loop is the core solver subroutine in screamer that populates and solves the large matrices. In this subroutine the large real*8 matrix and real*8 vectors are defined.

This Register Instruction Pointer (RIP) error is noted many times on the web. So far this available information has not helped me solve my problem. Note: the signed 4 byte integer limit is 2,147,483,647 so the error seems to be directly related to the use of a 32-bit pointer.

The gFortran compiler options include -mcmodel=medium that should take the pointers to 64 bits. -m64 has no effect. The total memory used by the primary matrix and vectors when the pointer limit is reached is greater than 2.4 GB. The confusing thing is that the code is fully 64 bit so I was not expecting 32-bit pointers. See below for 64-bit check.

rbspielman$ file screamer64

screamer64: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

The primary matrix and vector are all real*8 (64-bit). All large arrays in declared directly in this one subroutine and are not placed in common.

All other variables in common are ordered by size. real*8, real, int, char.

Simple test programs demonstrate that there is no fundamental memory limit. I can easily define static arrays to > 10 GB without a problem. Larger arrays also work but end up using virtual memory and slow down as expected.

Clearly there is some sort of memory or pointer size limit but I just cannot figure it out. The code matrix solvers are massive and more realistic test programs would be tedious.

(I also compile screamer in Ubuntu LINUX without a problem up to the same array limit as the Mac. Compilations in Windows 8 fail at the usual 2 GB memory limit NOT at the pointer limit.)

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't provide any code for us to analyze, so the only thing that comes in mind right now is that you might be still using some 32-bit variable to store the value of pointers, like `int my_reference = (int)some_pointer`, and therefore truncating its value.

Comment: The code is a bit long and complex to analyze. Even this specific subroutine is tedious. Is there some way to identify the pointer in question? Can we narrow down the possibilities. I don't think I truncated the pointer with a integer definition. I define over 50 variables as integer but few are used as pointers. I define most variables in header files that are common to nearly all subroutines. Should the pointers be real variables?

Comment: I did some search, and it seems the problem is related to MacOS. Try to link it with `-no_pie` active.

Comment: If you place -mdynamic-no-pic in the gFortran compile statement and -no_pie in the linker you do not get the error above but you get the following error ld: file too small (length=0) file 'screamer64' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 and a blank executable.

Comment: More information: I have compiled screamer with the -Wall switch on and the code compiles with no warnings. The batch files below:

Comment: rm *.o *.a MTRX RHS
gfortran -m64 -O3 -Wall -mcmodel=medium -c *.f
ar crv screamer64.a *.o
rm *.o
ranlib screamer64.a
g++ -m64 -O3 -mcmodel=medium -c cprog.cpp
g++ -m64 -O3 -mcmodel=medium -o screamer64 cprog.o screamer64.a /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.1.0/libgcc.a

Comment: subroutine main_loop

      include 'zdemmax.h'

      real*8 a(max_a), am_band(max_am,max_am), rhs_band(max_am)
      integer iptold, iptime, jdiv, nk, nzz

        call screamermatrix(a)

c max_am is 8190
c
      nk = ntot*2

      call bandmatrix(a,am_band,rhs_band,nk,nr,
     &                indexb,nadd_array,nb,topbranch,max_am)

c Solve the linear system using modified Gaussian elimination

      call solvermdgauss(am_band,rhs_band,nk,max_am,nadd_array,nb,nr)
      return
      end

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem with GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.1.0 in a Mac running 10.11.5 but the solution offered by the OP did not work for me.

However, I did find a solution: after systematically pruning my rather pedestrian legacy code, I found that every array has to be explicitly filled with something. You can't start filling it within your code. I know it sounds silly, but once I initialized every "real" array (32 bit, it is legacy code) with 0.0 before I did any I/O or other work, it linked without complaint.

And, yes, as with the OP, my code worked until I changed the size of an array.

The reason why this worked may be in the contents of this bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63793 but I am not good enough to tell you how to come up with a better workaround. My only guess is that initializing every array at the beginning favors the GOT instead of the RIP. (When will this be fixed? I just don't know how to push this up the line and the bug report is dated 2014-11-09)

Comment: This is not going to be fixed, it is old and has status UNCONFIRMED. It receives no attention now. You can try to give it some attention there if you think it is a legitimate bug.